# How to set an image's src from the API response?

Tags: javascript, html, api, authentication, system

I have this code that gets an image from the Minecraft API via uuid or username. It gets the value from an input tag.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="nameinput" placeholder="Username"/>
<img src="" id="display"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/login-page.js"></script>
```

Js:

```
document.querySelector("#nameinput").oninput = function(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onload = function() {
        // Grab data and assing feilds
        var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        var uuid = response.id;
        
        if (typeof(uuid) == "undefined") {
            response.id = "steve";
        }
        
        document.querySelector("#display").src = "https://crafatar.com/avatars/" + uuid + "?overlay&size=512";
    };

    request.open("GET", "https://api.year4000.net/minecraft/" + document.querySelector("#nameinput").value, true);
    request.send();
}
```

Basically, I want to move the image from the API over to display it in the image tag. How do I do this?

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: No, I basically have some code getting an image from the Minecraft API and I want to take the image to the HTML page. (index.html)

Comment: What is your precise goal? What did you try and what is not working?

Comment: My goal is to make a profile picture system using the user's Minecraft account skin and username. I tried putting in the display tag on the index file too but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using `addEventListener` instead of setting the `oninput` attribute.

```js
const nameInput = document.querySelector("#nameinput");
const img = document.querySelector("#display");

nameInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
    
    // Don't do anything if the value is empty
    if (this.value === '') return;
    
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onload = function () {
        const response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        const { id } = response;
        img.setAttribute('src', `https://crafatar.com/avatars/${id}?overlay&size=512`);
    };
    request.open("GET", "https://api.year4000.net/minecraft/" + this.value, true);
    request.send();
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nameinput" placeholder="test123" /><br>
<img id="display" src="" />
```

Comment: But how do I transfer it over to the index.html file?

Comment: Please define "transfer". Did you mean you want to show the same image to any user who visits the page? Then why don't you just "hard-code" the image source without all this JavaScript?

Comment: No because the user searches up his/her own username on the page and then uses it as the profile picture.

Comment: How will the page know which user is viewing the page? How will the page know which username to load? I think you want to implement user profiles, which require a server-side application and database?